# TSQL pivoting a table without an aggregation

Tags: sql, pivot, row

I have this table

```
name           hourOfDay                        score
bill             1                              22
bill             2                              28
bill             3                              29
bill             4                              24
bill             5                              34
```

and would like this table

```
name                  1            2            3          4            5 

bill                  22           28           29         24           34
```

Right now I'm doing this with tons of joins, is there a fast way to do this? My table is too large to use joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` and an aggregation anyway. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT name, HourOfDay, Score FROM YourTable) YT
PIVOT(MIN(Score) FOR HourOfDay IN ([1],[2],[3],.....,[24])) AS PT
```

You can use `MIN` or `MAX`, since it should be the same result.